# How can I generate high feature point images for recognition within an Augmented Reality app?

Tags: image, augmented-reality

I need to automatically generate 300-400 images (for a print medium) which will be used by an AR app (using ARCore).

- The printed physical image ideally would be 5" x 8" but can be 5" x 5" as well.
- The printed physical image ideally would be in Black & White.

I can of course use a QR code generator, but am open to use something better if it exists. There is no text / URL that needs to be encoded in the resultant image - I am just trying to choose something that makes things very easy for the ARCore / image recognition piece.

Comment: How have you tried generating your images so far? Are there any aspects you're unsatisfied with that answers could focus on helping you improve? Since basically any high-contrast image with plenty of corners and low symmetry will work, the space of working images might be much larger than the space of images that you find desirable for your application - so tell us more about what you specifically want to change.

Comment: Hi @DMGregory - I'm using QR codes, expanded to about 5" x 5" - they do work fine, but (a) look ugly, (b) create a pixelation distortion because of the image expansion. I can resolve (b) by looking up additional tools to create a "large" QR code (instead of expanding the small one) - but was seeking the community's inputs on whether there was something better that can be used overall (with better aesthetic appeal).

Comment: "Better aesthetic appeal" is pretty subjective. Can you offer a visual style target to make this more concrete?

Comment: Apologies for being vague - it's completely open at the moment and I am open to new ideas. These will need to be printed so will be viewed by people when not viewed through an AR view - and it would be nice if the image was interesting / appealing / soothing to the eye rather than a blocky QR code. The other thing is that the image should ideally be something I can generate - or there should be 300-400 variations which I can use readily. The black-and-white criteria can be relaxed. Sorry again for not having anything more specific.